# PHP not getting text from html textbox

Tags: php, html, variables, textbox

I am trying to set up a basic textbox that when the submit button is pressed, it e-mails the contents of the box to me. The problem is that I keep getting blank emails. The PHP code for some reason is not accessing the textbox input.

```
//Two Email Lines
$email_to = "contact@mywebsite.com";
$email_subject = "AUTO: REQUEST";

//Set equal to email form textbox
$email_form = $_POST['e3text'];


$email_message = "Email: " . $email_form . "";

//Create email headers
@mail($email_to, $email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

The HTML is below

```
    <div id="form">

    <form method="post" action="Email_Form_Script.php" 
      enctype="text/plain" 
      onsubmit="window.open('FormPopUp.html','popup','width=500,height=500,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');" >
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="e3text" id="emailForm" 
           value="Enter your e-mail address" 
           onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your e-mail address') { this.value = '' }" 
           onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value = 'Enter your e-mail address' }" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="email2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value=""/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Let em clarify something. The e-mail is not completely empty. Its contents are "Email:      ", as stated in the PHP code. It keeps reading the $email_form variable as blank.

Comment: html and php codes are in a same page ?

Comment: No, separate files. The php code is accessed through the action method of the form element.

Comment: You still don't actually have the textfield anywhere in your form. We got a good ways into this in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332623/php-not-getting-text-from-textbox. If the `e3text` contains only email address, you need to get a body from somewhere. It's simply not in your form - where does it come from?

Comment: remove this from your code : enctype="text/plain"

Answer (score 0):

remove enctype="text/plain" from the form tag. it works

Email_Form_Script.php

```
$email_to = "contact@mywebsite.com";
$email_subject = "AUTO: REQUEST";
//Set equal to email form textbox
$email_form = $_POST['e3text'];
echo $email_form;
$email_message = "Email: " . $email_form . "";
//Create email headers
@mail($email_to, $email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

and x.html

```
<form method="post" action="Email_Form_Script.php"  onsubmit="window.open('FormPopUp.html','popup','width=500,height=500,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');" >
<div>
<input type="text" class="text" name="e3text" id="emailForm" value="Enter your e-mail address" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your e-mail address') { this.value = '' }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value = 'Enter your e-mail address' }" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="email2"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value=""/>
</div>
```

it's working for me.

Comment: Removing it did not fix the problem for me. Is it possible that something else in my code is causing the variable to constantly be read as blank?

Comment: Still showing up as a blank variable input. Could it be a problem with the php settings on my server? Everything else in the php code is working, and I am getting an e-mail, but php is still reading the e3text as blank.

Comment: copy paste the edited answer. and echo $email_form before sending. that code is working for me. maybe you have a problem somewhere else

Comment: I copied code exactly and tried it. Same problem. I cannot figure out how an error elsewhere in the code (it all compiles fine) would cause the textbox to be read as blank. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean this (echo $email_form;) prints nothing? Weird problem

Comment: Prints nothing. I can not figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: The problem has got to be centered around the $email_form variable, it is always reading $POST_['e3text']; as null, which it isn't.

Comment: Remove this : onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your e-mail address') { this.value = '' }" and tell me it's working plx :D

Comment: Still nothing :( Thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: ywc :). Dose following codes work on your computer (not mail function just echo result). try it. maybe there is something wrong with your server.

Comment: Echo works when I set it to a standard string ('hello world') but still reading the $email_form as blank. This was offline.